# How to Sort/Arrange the JSON Object keys in android?

Tags: android, json, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

I am creating JSONArray from JSONObject in android. The JSONArray that i wanted to be is:
**[{"last_name":"cruz",
"first_name":"juan",
"middle_name":"sam"}]**

but it appears
**[{"first_name":"cruz",
"last_name":"juan",
"middle_name":"sam"}]**

how can I arrange the array in order that I wanted?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1. prepare a LinkedHashMap object with elements

2. convert it to JSONObject
```

**Example:**

```
Map obj = new LinkedHashMap();
obj.put("a", "String1");
obj.put("b", new Integer(1));
obj.put("c", new Boolean(true));
obj.put("d", "String2");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(obj);
```

download this library:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

save all the files in a new package in your project

instead of using **org.json.JSONObject** use **your.package.JSONObject** which you added from the downloaded library.

now open **JSONObject.java** file and change **HashMap()** to **LinkedHashMap()** in the constructor

```
public JSONObject(Map map)
```

This will make the JSONObject store data in the order you entered the values using put.

Answer (score 0):

You can't maintain the order of `JSONObject` response, because it is itself mentioned in the documents.

An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

I had faced the same problem and then i need to use either the gson library or to make json by ur logic..

```
An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.
```

Best of luck.!